# Nlog with MongoDB connection and target

Tags: mongodb, logging, nlog

I am trying to use a logger that will log into MongoDB, but I can not get it to work. In the same configuration i have set up the loggers to log using an email and file and both work just fine.

Here is my NLog.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.MongoDB"/>
  </extensions>
  <!-- 
  See http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file 
  for information on customizing logging rules and outputs.
   -->
  <targets>
    <target xsi:type="File" name="file" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${shortdate}.log"
               layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message}" />

    <target xsi:type="Mongo"
       name="mongoDefault"
       connectionString="mongodb://localhost/nlog"
       collectionName="cdss"
       cappedCollectionSize="26214400">
      <property name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <property name="ThreadName" layout="${threadname}" />
      <property name="ProcessID" layout="${processid}" bsonType="Int32" />
      <property name="ProcessName" layout="${processname:fullName=true}" />
      <property name="UserName" layout="${windows-identity}" />
    </target>


    <target name="TcpOutlet" xsi:type="Chainsaw" address="tcp4://localhost:4505" > </target>

    <target name="Email" xsi:type="Mail"
                smtpServer="localhost"
                smtpPort="25"
                smtpAuthentication="None"
                enableSsl="false"
                from="ssss@sdsdfs"
                to="ssss@sdsdfs" html="true"
          />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file,TcpOutlet,mongoDefault,Email" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="file,TcpOutlet,Email,mongoDefault" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

I have installed the Nlog.Mongo nugget also. My database is called nlog. Whatever i do, the loggers do not write in the mongodb. I am using NLogger.

Comment: did you fix it ? if you did please share here. I also having same problem like yours.

Comment: You may want to add 
    throwExceptions="true" internalLogFile="NLogError.log" internalLogLevel="Error" autoReload="true"
to your <nlog> properties to see if there is any overall error you aren't seeing.

Another difference I see is that you are using property instead of field elements. For us it is:
    <field name="ThreadID" layout="${threadid}" bsonType="Int32" />